# SQLite Plugin on cordova 3.5.0 is not working

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

I am new to Cordova Android development and this my first post to Stack Overflow. I am trying to create a Android Listview using data from a Pre-populated SQlite database as the listview Item names and when clicked to those listview items, a new page will be opened using the data from the same SQLite Database with detailed information. (for example "page 1" will have a listview dynamically created using data from a Pre-populated SQlite database and when clicked a listview item a new page "Page 2" will opened with related data stored in the same database like Branch names in the "Page 1" and Branch details in the "Page 2"). I have installed the Sqlite Plugin from Git Hub but no luck as yet. Can anyone help me to on this matter? Any query will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

N.B. I am using Cordova 3.5.0 CLI with Eclipse for development and Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean Mobile(not the emulator but a real mobile) to Test and my code is as follows----

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/shiplu.css.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/list.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "gmapdata"});

 db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
// create table

function populateDB(tx) {
 tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS markers');
 tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS markers (id INT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , name VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL, address     VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL , lat FLOAT( 10, 8 ) NOT NULL , lng FLOAT( 10, 8 ) NOT NULL , status VARCHAR, num VARCHAR DEFAULT (null) , zone VARCHAR, district VARCHAR)');
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO markers VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [2,'Motijheel Branch (AD)','161 Motijheel Commercial Area,  \n Dhaka- 1000 \n Ph: 9569350 (D) 7125266, 9564190, 01715028067 \n Fax: 9567664 ',23.722222,90.42171,'',NULL,'Corporate','Dhaka']);
 queryDB(tx);
}

// form the query
function queryDB(tx) {
tx.executeSql("SELECT name, address, district, zone from markers;", [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}
// Display the results
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
var len = results.rows.length;
//alert("results.rows.length: " + results.rows.length + " [should be 2]");

if(len>0)
{

document.write("<ul data-role='listview'>");

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { // loop as many times as there are row results

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=
    "<li><a href='#'>"+ results.rows.item(i).name +"</a></li>";
}
document.write("</ul>");
}
// Transaction error callback
function errorCB(err) {
console.log("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}
// Success error callback
function successCB() {
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>


<div data-role="page" data-theme="f" id="br_list">


<div role="banner" class="ui-bar-a ui-header" data-role="header">
            <a data-theme="F" href="index.html" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-a" data-icon="arrow-l"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Back</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-l ui-icon-shadow"></span></span></a>
            <h1 aria-level="1" role="heading" tabindex="0" class="ui-title">Branch List</h1>
</div>


<div class="segment">

    <div id="output" align ="center"><img src="img/loading.gif"></div>

</div>

<div data-role="footer" >
                <h4>********</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to tell us what are the errors or behaviour you are experiencing in you app. Are you getting any data? Have you tried alert() call for debugging.? why don't you use an emulator?. The populateDB() will called every time you open the app. This will in turn fire the **INSERT** sql **every time**. As you have created the table **markers** with **id** as primary key. This insert will fail since you are inserting a record with id=2 again and as a result populateDB() will fail.

Comment: Thx for ur response. First of all I am new in Cordova. No, I am not getting any data yet. I haven't used the alert() call for debugging. I am using my phone for testing because its fast, my emulator takes days to start and for the ID part this is an unique number for every Branch in the table and not a auto-incremented one. Hope, I have given the clarifications u have asked. Thnx again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using any Javascript editor for your work. You need to download a good JS editor for your eclipse, that will
highlight any syntax error in  your code. If you have any syntax error your real device will not show any message and
it will fail silently.

I would advice you to **remove all jquery code** from you app and just test the cordova functionality. Once you get your cordova database functionality working you can than add your jquery code.

Have you added SQLite plugin to your project. If you have not, than the following line in your code will not work.

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "gmapdata"});
```

You need to use instead the cordova core database API. Please refer the cordova link Here for reference
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html
example code below.

```
var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
```

Also when you are testing on a Real device or emulator. You need to make sure that you uninstall the app everytime you test your app. 
you can use alert() calls instead as shown below.

```
// Transaction error callback
function errorCB(err) {
alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}
// Success error callback
function successCB() {
    alert("successCB() called");
}
```

Also you can add **queryDB()** in the Last insert call as shown below.
also note I have added the **errorCB()** to the insert call has well to warn about any errors.

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO markers VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', 
[2,'Motijheel Branch (AD)','161 Motijheel Commercial Area,  \n Dhaka- 1000 \n Ph: 9569350 (D) 7125266, 9564190, 01715028067 \n Fax: 9567664 ',23.722222,90.42171,'',NULL,
'Corporate','Dhaka'],queryDB,errorCB);
//queryDB(tx);
```

Change the definition of the queryDB as

```
function queryDB(tx, results) {...}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions and it works but only if I call it as index page but when I try to call it using a link or from another page it shows nothing.

Comment: @shiplu_khan Please raise a new question. If the answer resolves your current question, mark it as answered so that it will be useful for other users.

Comment: my problem is solved partially, if u kindly follow my previous comment. What I am trying to achieve is calling the said page from index page and show some details in the third page. can u help me on this matter ?

Comment: How are you calling the the "details" page.? You need to specify the URL. If it is in the same location as the index.html, you have to only specify the name of the page. If it is located on a server you need to specify the complete URL.

Comment: index page>branch list(fetched from the sqlite database) in a listview>branch details fetched from same local sqlite DATABASE(like branch name, address,  zone, district)

Comment: I am not able to understand where you are stuck. Are index page(**index.html**) and listview (**listview.html**) two separate html pages? which **folder/Server** are the HTML pages located? Have you written the database codes on both the pages? Can you post your code using pastebin website http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Sorry for taking ur time. You can see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483857/how-to-pass-values-in-jquery-mobile[/link]. This is exactly what I want to achieve. Sorry for ur time again. But I am new to cordova and JQM. Pls keep in mind.